# ASP.NET app gives SocketException periodically: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: asp.net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

We have ASP.NET app: BotFramework + LUIS.

Chats: Teams, WebChat.

The issue happens periodically in different environments and it completely stops bot sometimes.

Error text from the logs: "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (169.254.169.254:80) An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions." when App is trying to call GET "/metadata/instance" (http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2020-06-01)

Callstack:

```html
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<ConnectToTcpHostAsync>d__97.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<ConnectAsync>d__96.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync>d__98.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<AddHttp11ConnectionAsync>d__73.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1+<WaitWithCancellationAsync>d__1.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<GetHttp11ConnectionAsync>d__75.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync>d__83.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+<SendAsyncCore>d__8.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Inner exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException handled at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<ConnectToTcpHostAsync>d__97.MoveNext:
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException (System.Net.Sockets, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult (System.Net.Sockets, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+<<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0>d.MoveNext (System.Net.Sockets, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<ConnectToTcpHostAsync>d__97.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
```

We expect that it is a socket exhaustion issue

- [https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/03/01/Deep-Dive-into-TCP-Connections-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html#:~:text=ddd.%E2%80%9D%20The%20maximum%20connection%20limits,per%20B3%2FS3%2FP3%20instance](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/03/01/Deep-Dive-into-TCP-Connections-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html#:%7E:text=ddd.%E2%80%9D%20The%20maximum%20connection%20limits,per%20B3%2FS3%2FP3%20instance))

We found all possible reasons in the code (reusing HttpClient etc), scaled up AppService plan, but still seeing the error in AppInsights logs (but didn't see that Bot is down at least).

Maybe somebody experienced the same issue?

Thank you

Comment: Is this webchat? Direct Line ASE? Where is the /metadata/instance endpoint?

Comment: WebChat & Teams, no DirectLine
"Where is the /metadata/instance endpoint" - sorry, didn't get a question

Comment: What application is the `/metadata/instance` endpoint implemented on? Why are you calling it?

Comment: We are not calling it explicitly, seems to be called by MS infrastructure

Comment: Ok, but which app is it that is making the call, and which app is receiving the call?

Comment: We have Teams bot, that is hosted as ASP.NET app. Or maybe I am not following your question?

Comment: Which Azure application that you have deployed is making this call? Which application is `169.254.169.254:80`?

Comment: This is was we try to find out)
This is Azure Metadata address: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service?tabs=windows

Answer (score 2):

The error looks like the socket got busy with some other process.

use `netstat -o`

to find the port which is busy with some other process.

```
netstat -ano | find "your port number"
```

This can also with the reason of range issue of the socket. Check it with

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

Final step: Try to **restart** the **Host Network Service** on windows service program

```
net stop hns
net start hns
```

Check with the socket version: Here are some supporting documents

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-reconnect-to-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connectasync?view=net-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

[similar](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/3859)

Comment: What is `"your port number"` for an outgoing connection attempt?